# Magento custom links get active set

Tags: magento, url, foreach

Hi I am trying to get the active state for my foreach loop for my magento site.
I have have tried everything, but it just wont work.. here is my code:

```
ksort($catArr);


foreach($catArr as $postion=>$catId){
$_category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
?>
<?php
if($_category->getIsActive() )
{
$caturl = $_category->getURL();
$catname = $_category->getName();
?>

<?php if($_category->getdata('left_menu')): ?>

<a  href="<?php echo "$caturl" ?>" > <li class="leftnav" ><div class="nav-name">
<?php echo $catname ?></div></li></a>
<?php endif ?>
<?php 
}
?>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to check category is active or not. If so the following line of code may be helpful to you if is_active is in the collection.

```
$_category->getData('is_active')
```

If you want to add it in the collection then use

```
addFieldToSelect('is_Active')
```

Comment: I am running magento 1.6.1 I am actually trying to get the active state for this part: <a  href="<?php echo "$caturl" ?>" > <li class="leftnav" ><div class="nav-name">
<?php echo $catname ?></div></li></a> so if the link has been click th <a should be <a class="current"

Comment: Find my new answer. Hope thats what you need.

Comment: I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home error when using your code. 

foreach...

<a  href="<?php echo "$caturl" ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getdata('meta_title') ?>" <?php if($category->getId()==$current_category_id): ?> class="current" <?php endif ?>
    > <li class="navig" ><div class="navig-name"><?php echo $catname ?></div></li></a>

foreach end.....

Answer (score 0):

```
/*to get current category ID*/
$category_nav_obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$current_category= $category_nav_obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_category_id = $current_category->getId();

/*Then loop as per your code*/

foreach(....):

if($category->getId()==$current_category_id):
  /*do whatever you want to highlight the category*/
endforeach;
```

Comment: I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home error